# Removing A part of Cell value in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to remove a part from cell values but its not working.

Sample content of a cell:(Sample Input)

```
="*sls*lmt"&CONCATENATE("_",'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns\XL-EZ Addin.xla'!COLUMNLETTER(C14),TEXT(ROW(),"0"))&"_sel*range(status)*0*GOOD|OK|0|#00D700|0|100|80*NOT GOOD|NG|0|#FFFF00|0|79|50*FAULTED|FAULTED|0|#FF0000|1|49|0"
```

Sample Output:

```
="*sls*lmt"&CONCATENATE("_",!COLUMNLETTER(C14),TEXT(ROW(),"0"))&"_sel*range(status)*0*GOOD|OK|0|#00D700|0|100|80*NOT GOOD|NG|0|#FFFF00|0|79|50*FAULTED|FAULTED|0|#FF0000|1|49|0"
```

and I want to remove this part from value

```
'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns\XL-EZ Addin.xla'
```

Here is what I have tried

```
Sub UpdateSheetButton()
Dim subStr1 As String
Dim subSrrt2 As String

Dim pos As Integer

For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
pos = InStr(Cell.Value, "'C:\")
If pos >= 1 Then
  subStr1 = Split(Cell.Value, "'C:\", 1)
  subStr2 = Split(Cell.Value, "\AddIns\XL-EZ Addin.xla'", 2)
  Cell.Value=subStr1 +subStr2 
  End If
Next

End Sub
```

**Error:**
Runtime error '13'
Type Mismatch
on this line

```
pos = InStr(Cell.Value, "'C:\")
```

Comment: Why do you want to use VBA for this? You can use Ctrl + H to do a find and replace?

Comment: This is a part of Excel Addin that's why i am using VBA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of your Type Mismatch error is this: `Split` returns an array, but you're assigning it to a String.  So you need to declare your variables like this:

```
Dim subStr1() As String
Dim subStr2() As String ' caution: there is a typo here in your code
```

Also, `Split` is a bit clumsy to work with. I'd go for string functions like `InStr` and `Mid` instead.

Moreover, If I understand correctly, you're trying to modify the cell's *formula*. However, your existing code looks at the cell's *value*. Not the same thing. Change `.Value` to `.Formula`.

Finally, your sample output is not a valid formula. Get rid of the `!` before `COLUMNLETTER`:

```
="*sls*lmt"&CONCATENATE("_",!COLUMNLETTER(C14),TEXT(ROW(),"0"))&"_sel*range(status)*0*GOOD|OK|0|#00D700|0|100|80*NOT GOOD|NG|0|#FFFF00|0|79|50*FAULTED|FAULTED|0|#FF0000|1|49|0"
                            ^
                          no good
```

With all this in mind, a better way to accomplish your task is this:

```
Function RemoveTextBetween(ByVal strInput As String, _
    ByVal strStartCut As String, ByVal strEndCut As String) As String

    Dim iStartCut As Long
    Dim iEndCut As Long
    iStartCut = InStr(strInput, strStartCut)
    iEndCut = InStr(strInput, strEndCut) + Len(strEndCut)
    RemoveTextBetween = Left(strInput, iStartCut - 1) & Mid(strInput, iEndCut)
End Function
```

Example usage:

```
cell.Formula = RemoveTextBetween(cell.Formula, "'C:\", "\AddIns\XL-EZ Addin.xla'!")
```

Note how I added `!` at the end to make sure it gets cut out.

Comment: Every thing working fine by using your answer but at the end when I try to assign formula to cell it throws error saying  " Run time error '1004'Application defined or object defined error"

Comment: Does the formula look right? Is the sheet protected and the cell locked?

Comment: Here is the formula after removal of substring ="*txt*lmt"&CONCATENATE("_",!COLUMNLETTER(),TEXT(ROW(),"0"))&"*range*0*" and neither sheet nor cell is locked or protected..

Answer (score 6):

I wonder why are you using VBA for such a simple task. You can use the inbuilt method.

**WAY One (NON VBA)**

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to bring the `Find and Replace` Dialog Box and use that to replace the text.

**WAY Two (VBA)**

If you still want to use VBA then simply record a macro for the above. There is **no need** to use a loop. For example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim sFind As String
    Dim sNew As String

    '~~> Example. Chnage as applicable
    sFind = "Sum"
    sNew = "Max" 'or sNew = "" in case you want to remove the above text

    '~~> For Complete Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells
        .Replace What:=sFind, Replacement:=sNew, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    End With

    '~~> For a Column
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(1)
        .Replace What:=sFind, Replacement:=sNew, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    End With

    '~~> For a range
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")
        .Replace What:=sFind, Replacement:=sNew, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Replace` to substitute text in the cell's `Formula` property, i.e.

```
A1    B1    C1    D1    E1
 a     b     c     d     =CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1,D1,"Something Else")
```

Let's say I want to remove the "Something Else" from the formula:

```
Sub removefromformula()

    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Me.[E1]

    Debug.Print r.Formula

    r.Formula = Replace(r.Formula, ",""Something Else""", "")

    Debug.Print r.Formula

End Sub
```

This returns:

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1,D1,"Something Else")
=CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1,D1)
```

In the immediate window.